# 415 Unsupported Media Type con el fetch desde React.js a una api de Django

Tags: reactjs, django

Estoy teniendo unos problemas terribles para poder conectar mediante fetch mi aplicacion de REACT.js y la api que he creado con Django framework.
La api está testeada y reque testeada y los endpoints funcionan perfectamente, por lo que deduzco que el problema está en mi front.

El problema reside en que estoy intentando registrar usuarios desde el front de forma sencilla, solo tengo un email, password y un check para indicar si es o no administrador.

EL error que me sale actualmente es un 415 unsoported Media Type, pero revisando tanto la api como la petición debería aceptar JSON

Aqui os dejo parte de mi codigo:

REGISTER.JSX

```js
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';

    const Register = () => {
        return fetch(url + "/api/auth/register/", {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',

            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: 'email',
                password: 'password',
                is_staff: 'is_staff',
            }),
        }).then(response => response.json())

    }

    export default Register;
```

BODY.JSX

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import Register from '../service/register.jsx';
    import './body.css';

    const Body = () => {
        const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
        const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
        const [is_staff, setIsStaff] = useState(false);

        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            Register(email, password, is_staff);
        }

        return (
            <div className="body">
                <div className="container">

                    <Form className="form">
                        <h4 className="User"> Perfil </h4>

                        <div className="float-left"> Usuario
                            <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked={true} />
                        </div>

                        <div className="float-right">
                            Administrador
                            <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" onChange={e => setIsStaff(e.target.value)} />
                        </div>


                        <br />

                        <Form.Group className="xl-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                            <Form.Label><h4>Correo Electronico</h4></Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group className="xl-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                            <Form.Label><h4>Contraseña</h4></Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                        </Form.Group>


                        <Button className="buttonSubmit" type="Registrar" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                            Registrar
                        </Button>
                    </Form>

                </div >




            </div >


        );
    }

    export default Body;
```

Comment: Se que es una tontería, pero me estraña que la ruta de la api termine en `/`.

Comment: Buen apunte, no me habia dado cuenta pero si le quito el / me da error 500. Lo he probado en insomnia y tiene que llevarla.

Comment: Cambia el mode a cors ya que al ser no-cors se envia todo como texto plano y no como json

Comment: He cambiado el mode a cors y he añadido al headers el ``` 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',```  pero me salta el error: *****localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*****

Comment: intentaste quitar el stringify en el body? ´´´JSON.stringify(´´´´??

Comment: no ha habido suerte Nicolas, mismos errores

Answer (score 0):

Por fín después de muchas vueltas lo he resuelto, el problema estaba en
chrome por lo que instale la extension de CORS, poner mode: "cors" y no poner "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*". :)